# Javascript alert issue on form: Alert prompt keeps appearing

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, checkbox

Can't provide a link to this project due to NDA, but hopefully, the code I'll post will be more than sufficient to solve this.

I'm doing a simple PHP contact form. Nothing crazy. Two text input fields and a checkbox to validate age. If you leave the form unchecked, you can't enter the contest.

I have the validation working....to a point. Here's what is happening. When I keep the checkbox unchecked and I try to submit the form, I get an alert prompt saying I'm not 18 or over. The JS is like this:

```
if (!document.forms[0].age.checked)
{ 
    alert("Sorry, you must be over 18 to enter...Please check the over 18 box to proceed");  
}
```

That works, and I click "OK", but then the alert prompt immediately comes back! And I'm stuck essentially in a loop.

Anyone know how to properly do this so I can get the form to work?

Comment: What is the event that is calling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
if (!document.forms[0].age.checked) {
  alert("Sorry, you must be over 18 to enter...Please check the over 18 box to proceed");
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be checked in the form submit event (here inline but should be unobtrusive):

`<form onsubmit="return validate(this)"...`

and do

```
function validate(theForm) { 
  if (!theForm.age.checked) alert("Please...."); 
  return theForm.age.checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
    var validateForm = function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var formEl = document.forms[0].age;
       if (formEl.checked) {
           alert("Sorry, you must be over 18 to enter...Please check the over 18 box to proceed");
       }
       e.stopPropagation();
   }
```

Instantiate the function as you normally would, like:

```
 var button = document.getElementById('submit');
   button.addEventListener('click', validateForm, false);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/es5qpp5t/)